# Automatically adding inheritance as properties on constructor, javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, web-worker

I'm moving a (heavy) file-parser to a webworker. Webworkers can only return serialized json. Hence, I cant return function that gives me object that inherit from a specific class:

```
getCollection: function getCollection(cls) {
  if (!cls) {
    return this.myObjects;
  }
  let collection = cls.toUpperCase();

  let arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < this.nrOfObjects; i++) {
    if(classes[collection]){
      if (this.myObjects[i] instanceof classes[collection]) {
        arr.push(this.myObjects[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  return arr;
}
```

So for example `getCollection('product')` would return all instances that inherits from the class `product`

When I move the parsers to the webworker, I can't return this function. Is there anyway I can add the inheritance to my constructor in my classes instead?

```
export class Column extends BuildingElment {
  constructor(GlobalId, OwnerHistory, Name, Description) {
    super(GlobalId, OwnerHistory, Name);
    this.description = Description
    this.nameOfClass = 'Column';
    this.inheritance = ['Root', 'Product', 'BuildingElement'] // Can this be somehow automatically generated??
  }
}
```

Or if there is any other way I can work with webworkers and still get the inheritance.

Comment: What distinguishes these classes other than their class name? Filter the instances by that.

Comment: I don't have anything to filter on. I need quick way to get all instances that inherits from a class and from the webworker I can only get serialized data.

Comment: If they don't differ, why are they using different classes in the first place?

Comment: Well of course they differ. Do you mean I should check the arguments? E.g getCollectionWithArgs('GlobalId', 'OwnerHistory', 'Name') ? Could do that but it's not pretty. I rather do getCollection('Product')

Comment: Yes, that's one possibility. If you like it more pretty, have a mapping from `'Product'` to `['GlobalId', 'OwnerHistory', 'Name']` and use that. It's all about duck typing :-)

Comment: Hm. It's 750 classes. Quite time-consuming and error prone to do it manually. I was hopping for some neat built in function in javascript that returns the inherited classes.

Comment: Actually, [there is](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31644662/1048572), but class names shouldn't be trusted or thought of as unique in general.