# Access method of specific ancestor

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I'm currently trying to access the method of a specific ancestor in my dependency chain. Specifically, I want to run `ParentClass.logName()` from my initialized GrandChildClass. This is how I access the ParentClass prototype (approach taken from [Get parent class name from child with ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644662/get-parent-class-name-from-child-with-es6)).

```js
class AncestorClass {
    constructor (name, id){
        this.name = name + id;
    }
    logName () {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
    
}

class ParentClass extends AncestorClass {
    constructor (name, id) {
        super(name, 1);
        this.name = name + id;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    constructor (name, id) {
        super(name, 2);
        this.name = name + id;
    }
}

class GrandchildClass extends ChildClass {
    constructor (name, id){
        super(name, 3);
        this.name = name + id;
    }
}

const grandchild = new GrandchildClass('testName', 4);
const parent =  Object.getPrototypeOf((Object.getPrototypeOf(grandchild.constructor)));
console.log(parent);
const initParent = new parent();
initParent.logName();
```

So I got the prototype and initialized it with the `new` keyword but for some reason `initParent.logName()` returns NaN.

So how do I call to ParentClass.logName from my grandchild without initializing ParentClass directly?

Comment: Just call `grandchild.logName()` ? Not sure I understand what the problem is. In general, you never want to access a method of a *specific* ancestor, because the calling code should *never* know where exactly the method is defined. All it needs to know is that the object conforms to an interface. If `grandchild.logName()` doesn't solve your problem then you have to provide more information about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `grandchild.logName()` works...

Comment: ParentClass.prototype.logName.call(instanceOfGrandChild);

Comment: Also check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize parent with an empty constructor, which means both attribute are `undefined` and `undefined + undefined` gives `NaN`.

```
const initParent = new parent('foo', 1);
initParent.logName() // print 'foo1'
```

```js
class AncestorClass {
    constructor (name, id){
        this.name = name + id;
    }
    logName () {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
    
}

class ParentClass extends AncestorClass {
    constructor (name, id) {
        super(name, 1);
        this.name = name + id;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    constructor (name, id) {
        super(name, 2);
        this.name = name + id;
    }
}

class GrandchildClass extends ChildClass {
    constructor (name, id){
        super(name, 3);
        this.name = name + id;
    }
}

const grandchild = new GrandchildClass('testName', 4);
const parent =  Object.getPrototypeOf((Object.getPrototypeOf(grandchild.constructor)));
console.log(parent);
const initParent = new parent('foo', 1);
initParent.logName();
```