# Javascript polymorphism: how to access static attributes of inheriting class in static method of ("abstract") base class?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I would like to have a base class and an inheriting class. The base class should provide some general functionality which depends on the properties of the inheriting class.

=>How can I access the properties of the inheriting class in the base class?

Below is some example to illustrate the question (My question is not how to define an enum in JavaScript. The example is just for illustration.).

Example base class:

```
export default class Enum { 

    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;       
    }
}

Enum.values =  function(){
    return Object.values(INHERITING_CLASS);
};


Enum.forName = function(name){
    for(var enumValue of INHERITING_CLASS.values){
        if(enumValue.name === name){
            return enumValue;
        }
    }
    throw new Error('Unknown value "' + name + '"');
}
```

Example inheriting class:

```
import Enum from './enum.js';

export default class ColumnType extends Enum {  

    constructor(name, clazz){
        super(name);        
        this.associatedClass = clazz;
    }
}

ColumnType.Integer = new ColumnType('Integer', Number);
ColumnType.Double = new ColumnType('Double', Number);
ColumnType.String = new ColumnType('String', String);
```

I want to be able to access the static values of ColumnType with

```
ColumnType.values()
```

where the `values` function is provided by the base class Enum. Some for method `forName`.

If I would use "Enum" for the placeholder INHERITING_CLASS, the result is not correct.

=> How do I know that ColumnType is the currently inheriting class while being in the scope of the definition of the Enum class?

*Edit*

Here is a related question:

[Get parent class name from child with ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644662/get-parent-class-name-from-child-with-es6)

Their answer uses `instance.constructor`. However, in my static method I don't have an instance.

Comment: Javascript differs from classical inheritance, you may want to read up on Prototype in Javascript

Comment: Can you show how you would write this in Java? Surely you would declare a protected attribute with the values that the child class would need to overwrite?

Comment: Thank you for asking back. I *thought* I already did that in Java but it turns out it has been something different (non static).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier than I thought. When calling the static method `ColumnType.values()`, inside the values function `this` will actually provide the wanted Class as context:

```
export default class Enum { 

    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;       
    }
}

Enum.values =  function(){
    return Object.values(this);
};


Enum.forName = function(name){
    for(var enumValue of this.values){
        if(enumValue.name === name){
            return enumValue;
        }
    }
    throw new Error('Unknown value "' + name + '"');
}
```

Comment: I thought you were looking for a way to access properties of a child class from an parent's class object or parent's class. Seems like you were looking for some form of polymorphism, is that the case ?

Comment: The word polymorphism did not pop to my mind but you are right.

Comment: In that case you might want to rephrase the title of the thread, it's confusing imo :)

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is the prototype unless I misread the question

ColumnType.prototype.values()

Comment: How do I know that ColumnType is the currently inheriting class while being in the scope of the definition of the Enum class?

Comment: One thing I think you could do is call ColumnType.prototype.values.bind(this) and then within the parent implementation reference this though that might night be the cleanest solution. There's also a property on the function object called caller. So Function.caller would work. But it's also a somewhat dirty solution. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller