# How to get class parents id in html js (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, parent

I have a class. How do I know this class parents id.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get parent class name from child with ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644662/get-parent-class-name-from-child-with-es6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements in HTMl can have only one parent node. I am not sure if you want retrieve id of grandParent class in the example or not. If you want to retrieve ids of all the ancestor nodes, please update the question.

```js
const child = document.querySelector('.child') // Selecting the class you want to work with.
console.log(child);

const parent = child.parentElement.getAttribute('id') // Getting id of parent node.
console.log('parent id: ', parent);
```

```html
  <div id='1' class='grandParent'>
      <div id='2' class='parent'>
          <div id='3' class='child'>
            Hi
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```