# Get constructor name of object

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

How can I get name of object's class? I mean "Process" in this example[image]

I see two ways to get it. First one is to write a getter in this class like

```
 getClassName(){return "Process"}
```

But I suppose it will be an error if I try to call this method in object which doesn't belong to this class and hasn't got method like this.

And second one is using `object instanceof Process`. But maybe there is some way to make it better and more correctly?

Comment: What do you need this for? If it's supposed to have some actual purpose in your application, that explicit `getClassName` method is the way to go.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will it be possible to find out an object's class and module in ecmascript-harmony](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19279232/1048572)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get it from `name` on `constructor`:

```
console.log(object.constructor.name);
```

When you do `ex = new Example`, for instance, in the normal course of things that makes `Example.prototype` the prototype of the object that was created (`ex`), and the object inherits a `constructor` property from that object that refers back to the constructor (`Example`).

I say "in the normal course of things" because there are various ways those normal relationships can be changed. For instance, code could have overridden the `constructor` property with an own property on the object (`ex.constructor = somethingElse;`). To rule out that specific scenario, you could use:

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(object).constructor.name);
```

Live example:

```js
class Example1 {
}
const e1 = new Example1();
console.log(e1.constructor.name); // "Example1"

class Example2 {
    constructor() {
        this.constructor = "I'm special";
    }
}
const e2 = new Example2();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(e2).constructor.name); // "Example2"
```

The TC39 committee members that specify JavaScript were happy enough to use the instance's `constructor` property in `Promise`s when building the new promise that `then` and `catch` return (see Step 3 [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-promise.prototype.then) which goes [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-speciesconstructor) and reads `constructor` from the instance) (and in some other places), so you wouldn't be out on your own if you also used it. They don't even go to the prototype of the instance.

But yes, just for completeness, even if you go to the prototype for it, it's still possible for that to lead you astray, since the prototype's `constructor` property can also be mucked with:

```js
class Example {
}
Example.prototype.constructor = Object; // Why would anyone do this? People are weird.
const e = new Example();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(e).constructor.name); // "Object"
```

It's also possible to redefine the `name` on a function:

```js
class Example {
}
// Why would someone do this? People are weird.
Object.defineProperty(Example, "name", {
    value: "flibberdeegibbit"
});
const e = new Example();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(e).constructor.name); // "flibberdeegibbit"
```

So...caveat user.

---

Note that the function `name` property is new as of ES2015 (as is `class` syntax). If you're using `class` syntax via a transpiler, it may or may not set `name` correctly.

Comment: "*If you want to be a bit paranoid*" …you wouldn't use any `.constructor` or `.name` property :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Meh, there are degrees of paranoia. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you very much!!

Comment: To my knowledge, `name` is readonly in some browsers. The answer doesn't mention that `name` will be mangled in minified code, which is absolute no-no for using it in client side code.

Comment: @estus: `name` is read-only, but configurable (weird -- in my view -- but true), hence using `Object.defineProperty` above rather than using `.name = ...` As for mangled names in minified code, we're now well into the land of speculation, and since the name will still be the name of the function (mangled or otherwise)... (That said: I would have liked to see an answer to bergi's question on the question from the OP as to **why** they want this info...)

Comment: It's non-configurable in some V8 versions. Even if legacy Chrome versions are not taken into account, the support in Android browsers is harder to ignore, this will produce nasty bugs that are hard to detect and debug. These are good reasons for me to not recommend `name` by default - unless the question has `node.js` tag.

Comment: @estus: Just as well I didn't *recommend* using it then. I answered the question that was asked. I also included a couple of caveats around it.

Answer (score 8):

Generally `object instanceof Process` is desirable if it's known for sure that `object` originates from this class/function. There may be situations where this won't be so. The appearance of several `Process` can be caused by iframes, multiple package versions, etc.

There is [`name` property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310530/get-the-class-name-of-es6-class-instance) that already exists in regular functions class constructors. A known pitfall is that it will be mangled in minified code, so it is generally useless in browser JS, and its use can be considered an antipattern. `name` cannot be reassigned (in some browsers), so a separate property is needed to identify the class.

The proper way is to avoid this problem

> But I suppose it will be an error if I try to call this method in object which doesn't belong to this class and hasn't got method like this.

is to use a getter:

```
class Process {
  get className() { return 'Process'; }
  ...
}
```

Or a property:

```
class Process {
  ...
}
Process.prototype.className = 'Process';
```

As a result, there may be several `Process` classes that have `Process` `className` identifier. This may be desirable or not. While `instanceof` associates class instance with one particular class.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.constructor.name` on the object. Each object's constructor by default refers to his creation function, which has a [**name**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) property. It returns the name of the function.

```js
class SomeClass {

}

const obj = new SomeClass();

console.log(obj.constructor.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#Function_names_in_classes) property as follows:

```js
class Process {}

console.log(Process.name);

const process = new Process;

console.log(process.constructor.name);
```

This is the same way it works for normal prototypal inheritance using functions.